# Cosa significa "rispondere a tono"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> Poi si mise sullo scalino con Arnaldo; e gli fece una 
>   quantità di domande, su Bube, sulla famiglia di Bube. E il ragazzo **rispondeva a tono**, come se invece di avere quindici anni ne avesse venti o venticinque.

Quella che faceva tutte queste domande è Mara, la protagonista del romanzo.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "rispondere a tono" in questo brano. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tono1/) ho trovato questa definizione:

> *rispondere a tono*, rispondere a proposito

Tuttavia, continuo senza capire del tutto bene: non vedo la relazione tra rispondere a proposito delle domande di Mara e il fatto che Arnaldo rispondesse come se avesse venti o venticinque anni invece di quindici. Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "rispondere a tono" in questo brano?

Comment: L'idea è quella di un ragazzo che riesce a fare conversazione con un adulto senza farsi intimidire, usando espressioni efficaci e mantenendo un tono di voce che lo fa apparire sicuro di sé.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significa che la risposta è adeguata alla domanda. In musica uno è "in tono" quando mantiene la tonalità degli altri. Similarmente il "rispondere a tono" significa che le risposte sono date nella stessa maniera in cui le domande erano poste. Mara fa domande in modo adulto, ed il ragazzino le risponde nello stesso modo.

Un altro esempio potrebbe essere il ritornare una risposta pungente a qualcuno che ti insulta.

Come espressione non è ristretta solo ad un colloquio, può essere estesa ad ogni reazione adeguata all'azione che la ha causata: un atleta per esempio può "rispondere a tono" quando offre una prestazione allo stesso livello degli altri atleti suoi avversari. Puoi usare quest'espressione sia per cose positive che negative.

Answer (score 1):

Come aggiunta alla risposta di 
Erik vanDoren, vorrei riportare la definizione dell'espressione "rispondere a tono" del [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000032.jpg), che mi sembra un po' più chiara di quella del Treccani:

> – *Parlare, rispondere a tono*: ribattere in modo ade­guato, per le rime. 
>         *Fagiuoli*, II-140: Così diceste: e subito un frastuono / s'udì di 
>   quelle donne, e dir: E viva  /  viva  costei,  che  parlò  tanto  a tuono. *Nievo*, 599:  Ella mostrava ragionare col suo miglior sen­no,  e  dovetti rispondere a tono.  *Jahier*, 3-121:  Rispondeva  poco a tono, gli occhi assenti lontani beati.

Answer (score 0):

L'espressione indica una risposta completa e diretta, quella che darebbe una persona matura.